# java xml with tree structure

Tags: java, regex, xml

I know how to get xml elements of a file with this kind of code:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt2820850&plot=full&r=xml

Because there is a root element and an movie element with some info.

But in this link:

http://api.traileraddict.com/?film=fifty-shades-of-grey&count=1

I need the embed code of the movie, and this is the 3rd element of the tree, and I only know how to do it for max 2 structure. 
Also i should only have the iframe code to put in my webview element, but i don't have experience of working with regex in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you do not try to use regex, instead try something like this:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "http://api.traileraddict.com/?film=fifty-shades-of-grey&count=1";
    parse(url);
}

public static void parse(String strUrl) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    try (InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("embed");
        Node embedItem = nList.item(0);
        System.out.println(embedItem.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Here i have used DOM parser, instead, you could try sax or stax

Comment: I don't understand the nodelist part...

Comment: It is a list of nodes that have the name 'embed', since there is only one tag with the name 'embed', get the first one (its index begins with 0)

Comment: I want to use the code in a webview what do i actually need.  Because i searched the web for solutions but i only find YouTube  examples.  I need a code like webview.getEngine().load(???)

Comment: Do you mean, within the iframe? If so, then the text can be parsed using an html parser (jSoup is one of them if i am not wrong)